# Self join using case statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Below is the data in a table `Star`. I want a query which returns only 1 record per `StarID` per `assessdate` but if there are same `assessdate` for one `starid` then compare the `askdate` and return that record which has most recent `askdate`.

```
StarID   |  assessdate              |  artid |  pep |manager          |  Notes                   |  followup| askdate   
DEC1660  |  2016-05-18 00:00:00.000 | 20979  | Yes  |BRIGGS, SIMON    |NULL                      |  6 Weeks | NULL
DEC1660  |  2016-05-19 00:00:00.000 | 20982  | No   |BRIGGS, SIMON    |Other, sdf, AZT, TDF, RAL |  12 Weeks| 2016-05-11 00:00:00.000    
ANW4477  |  2016-05-27 00:00:00.000 |21008   | Yes  |Mundt, Susan     |NFV, DRV, MVC, Other, test|  6 Weeks | 2016-05-27 00:00:00.000  
ANW4477  |  2016-05-28 00:00:00.000 |21011   | No   |Henley, Rebecca  |NULL                      |  12 Weeks| NULL 
REP2893  |  2016-05-30 00:00:00.000 |21305   | Yes  |Henley, Rebecca  |AZT, 3TC                  |  12 Weeks| 2016-05-30 00:00:00.000  
REP2893  |  2016-05-30 00:00:00.000 |21305   | Yes  |Henley, Rebecca  |TDF, FTC                  |  12 Weeks| 2016-06-02 00:00:00.000
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH X AS (
    Select *
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StarID, assessdate 
                               ORDER BY askdate DESC) rn
    FROM Star )
SELECT * 
FROM X 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks M.Ali. Damnnn!!! I did not use DESC for askdate and so it did not work for me.